# Show that the problem of deciding whether a Turing machine prints something is undecidable

Tags: computer-science, computability, automata

I am unable to get the logic for showing that the problem of whether a Turing machine prints something is undecidable by showing that the halting problem reduces to it. Please guide me with this.

Answer (score 3):

Given any TM $M$, construct a TM $M'$ which is the same as $M$ except that the only time it will print something is just before halting. Then if I can decide the "printing problem", I can run my decision procedure on $M'$ and I have decided the halting problem on $M$.